# Can I transport jello shots?

Tags: united-states, alcohol, indiana

A party is coming up and I wanted to make jello shots for it.

I was then worried about open container laws. If I transport jello shots in a sealed Tupperware container in my trunk, could I get in trouble for an "open container" if I am 100% sober?

I am in Indiana, USA if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3):

Indiana's open container law is in [Section 9-30-15-3 (b) of the Indiana Code.](http://codes.findlaw.com/in/title-9-motor-vehicles/in-code-sect-9-30-15-3.html)

> (b) A person in a motor vehicle who, while the motor vehicle is in
>   operation or while the motor vehicle is located on the right-of-way of
>   a public highway, possesses a container:
>
> (1) that has been opened;
>
> (2) that has a broken seal;  or
>
> (3) from which some of the contents have been removed;
>
> in the **passenger compartment** of the motor vehicle commits a Class C
>   infraction.

The trunk of a car is not part of the passenger compartment, so alcohol in the trunk will not violate this law.

Paragraph (a) of the law gives some other exceptions and clarifications, for situations like RVs, limos, and vehicles that don't have a trunk.

Comment: The part missing is evidence that a "Jello shot" is subject to restriction: IC 7.1-1-3-5. According to subsection 2, it may not be restricted.

Comment: I think @user6726 is attempting a joke.  The subsection in question excludes from the definition of "alcoholic beverage" anything that is unfit for human consumption.